# How to export all images and videos from Photo Booth to finder?

Tags: photos, video, photo-booth

Images and videos can be exported from Photo Booth one by one by either

1. Right-clicking in the file in Photo Booth -> Export, or
2. Drop and dragging the image/video from Photo Booth into a finder folder

The problem is, neither method works for multiple images/videos: if you have n images/videos, you have to drop and drag ***n times***, which, needless to say, is *exceptionally* tedious.

How can multiple images / videos be exported from Photo Booth in one go? (i.e. avoiding manually doing it one by one)?

Note: if there's some work around to access the raw .png's .mov's, then that is just as good - the end result should be some image and video files that can be opened with any standard media viewers/players (not just Photo Booth)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest is probably to simply find the photos in Finder.

1. Open Finder
2. Locate the `PhotoBooth library` file (usually in `user/pictures`)
3. right click on it, hit `show package contents`
4. Copy all files from the `Pictures` folder (if you want to have the original photos without effects on them also copy the `Originals` folder)

You can read in a bit more detail here: [OSXdaily](https://osxdaily.com/2016/03/20/photo-booth-image-file-location-mac-os-x/)

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. Just another note, if you have many GB, opening two finder windows and dragging the files will simply cut/paste them (i.e. without making another copy), which is virtually instant (as opposed to copy/paste which may take some time)

Comment: True, but you'll screw up your Photo Booth library. I much rather have a *copy*, but of course that takes some time. Glad I could help though ;)

Comment: @stevec, hold down the alt key when dragging and the files will be copied. Making copies of images in the age of SSDs takes about no time. Seriously.